# Magento 2.1.9 frontend font icon extend

Tags: magento-2.1, mini-cart, fonts, icon

I need to change only one font icon -the cart icon. I tried a few guides:
https://www.classyllama.com/blog/icon-fonts-magento-2-foundation
http://rossmchugh.com/extending-magento2s-icon-font-system/
http://zanetabaran.com/magento-2-icons-custom-fonts/

but while these are working fine, my problem is that I need to replace all the 34 font icons of the frontend, because it replaces the default font-icon font. 
What I need is to expand the default so I can replace one or two only.
any help, please?

Answer (score 8):

1. You need open this website https://icomoon.io/app/#/select
2. Click on Import Icon purple button on the top choose your Luma-Icons.svg file from luma them.
3. You will get all icon Where you can add, edit and updates your icons.
4. Than click on generate font button on bottom
5. Than replace fonts your them.
6. php bin/magento s:s:d -f and php bin/magento c:f

[image]

Comment: that works great, but it needs to resize all the icons again to default size in the _theme.less

Comment: ignore the previous comment, that works great, thank you!

Comment: Your most welcome :)